# RegExp on Node.js cause indeterminated mode

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this regexp:

> /\|====(.*)====>((.*|\n|\r)*?)<====\1====\|/g

It match pattern such as

```
|==== Données ====>
    byteCode =
    {
        id : [],
        tag : [],
        ast : []
    };
<==== Données ====|
```

$1 indicate first capturing group, in this exemple ' Données '.

In Firefox the expected behavior is correct but in node.js it's a joke!
If you call this regexp with 'exec' the program enter in indeterminated mode, not gc error, no timeout, nothing... But program never ending... Why?

If you wish reproduce this, simply past this script in any terminal:

```
const regexp = /\|====(.\*)====>((.\*|\n|\r)*?)<====\1====\|/g;
const text = String.raw 
`
 |==== Données ====>
    byteCode =
    {
        id : [],
        tag : [],
        ast : []
    };
<==== Données ====|
`;
regexp.exec(text);
```

Thank you for reading and futur answer!

Comment: Interesting, can you re-try with `\|====([^=]*)====>([\s\S]*?)<====\1====\|`? Or better with `\|====([^=]*)====>([^<]*(?:<(?!====\1====\|)[^<]*)*)<====\1====\|`

Comment: Can you add complete code

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great thank, your two regexp are functionals! You know why my regexp is broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you escaped the `*` quantifier in `.\*` and made it a literal asterisk, not a quantifier.

BTW, the alternation you are using is highly inefficient. You can use `[\s\S]` to match any character including a newline:

```
/\|====([^=]*)====>([\s\S]*?)<====\1====\|/g
```

Where `([^=]*)` matches 0+ characters other than `=` and `[\s\S]*?` matches 0+ any characters but as few as possible. Or, better use an unrolled version which is more efficient:

```
/\|====([^=]*)====>([^<]*(?:<(?!====\1====\|)[^<]*)*)<====\1====\|/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mW3sU8/1)